# Dans cet article, "marcher" signifie manifester, faire la grève, ou autre ?

Tags: expressions, sens, afrique

Extrait de l'[article d'un journal en ligne malien](http://www.maliweb.net/news/armee/2012/03/22/article,56151.html):

> Parti pour dégoupiller la grenade du mécontentement des militaires qui
>   projetaient de marcher ce jeudi 22 mars 2012, le ministre de la
>   Défense, le général Sadio Gassama, a été hué par les militaires de la
>   caserne de Kati qui l’ont ensuite séquestré.

Dans ce contexte, que signifie "marcher" ?

Les militaires prévoyaient-ils de **manifester** le 22 mars ?
Ou prévoyaient-ils de se "**mettre à pied**" ?

Comment: En première lecture 'manifester', après votre réflexion et lecture du journal cela devient moins décidable, ... avec envie de solliciter les maliens (ou Nouhoum Dicko) pour découvrir les connotations locales du verbe.

Comment: Je pense que c'est un usage d'Afrique francophone. En France, je dirais *défiler* ou *manifester* s'il s'agit de montrer son mécontentement sans plus, et *marcher sur [le palais présidentiel, par exemple]* s'il s'agit de renverser le pouvoir. À moins que les militaires en question n'aient projeté de *marcher* dans le sens de partir au front?

Comment: J'ai posté un commentaire demandant un eclaircissement. Pas de réponse pour l'instant.

Comment: Ca prête à équivoque! Le concours de quelqu'un y ayant séjourné pourrait tomber bien à pic, je pense.

Answer (score 3):

Dans ce contexte, je pense que c'est "marcher sur le pouvoir/gouvernement". Prendre le contrôle du pouvoir/gouvernement. Donc faire un coup d'état.

Answer (score 2):

> Parti pour dégoupiller la grenade du mécontentement des militaires

Signifie que le mécontentement des militaires était connu et revendiqué, sinon le ministre ne serait pas allé les voir.

> projetaient de marcher ce jeudi 22 mars 2012

Cette *marche* était prévue et connue des autorités. Il ne peut donc pas s'agir d'une opération militaire ou d'un complot qui auraient exigé le secret.

À partir de ce contexte:, je pense qu'on peut exclure le sens militaire de *marcher sur* signifiant *envahir*, *attaquer*, *renverser le pouvoir*. Je comprends donc que les militaires avaient prévu de manifester le 22 mars. Cela n'exclut cependant pas une suite violente à cette manifestation, d'où l'expression:

> la *grenade* du mécontentement